# Why can't I return the modified str_func function back to the main function?

Tags: python, string, function, replace

I have gotten about 80% of this program done but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to replace the vowels with asterisks and print the new string.

Instructions are as follows:

1. prompt the user to enter his/her first name.
2. output the number of letters in the name.
3. print all of the letters in the name separated by a space, all on one line.
4. print the name in all upper case.
5. use one slicing to make a new string from the name, but without the first and last letters.
6. print this new string.
7. pass the original name to a function named str_func.
8. inside the str_func function:

   - replace the vowels in the name with asterisks
   - return the modified name back to main
   - back in main, print the string returned by str_func.

My code so far:

```
def main():

    name = input('Enter your first name: ')

    print(name)

    ### print name with spaces in between characters
    spaces = ''
    for ch in name:
        spaces = spaces + ch + ' '
    print(spaces[:-1]) # to get rid of space after e

    print('name in caps is,',name.upper())  # print name in all caps

    print('After chopping the name we get',name[1:4])

    print(str_func)

def str_func():

    str_func = name.replace('a','*')
    return str_func



main()
```

A friend of mine has helped somewhat stating I have issues with my str_func function:

> The function is supposed to take the name as an argument in the main function when you call it.
>   You don't print it. You call it, something like this:
>   new_name = str_func(name)
>
> Define str_func() like this. I put in some pseudocode for you.
>
> ```
> def str_func(name):
>        ###make a string containing the vowels
>        ###loop through the name
>        ###replace vowel if found with *
>        ### after loop, return the name
> ```

Please help!!

Comment: You're redefining `str_func` inside of `str_func`.

Comment: Your friend's pseudocode suggestions are quite good. Do you understand them? Do you understand how functions and their arguments work? StackOverflow isn't here to do your homework for you (though you might get lucky and somebody will answer anyway). You need to ask us a specific question about the issue you're having, not just go "I'm stuck, help".

Comment: Just a note that you’re slicing your string using `name[1:4]`. Are you sure that the input will always be 5 characters long?

Comment: for this particular example, i'm gonna keep the name to always be 5 characters long. Blckknght I am very aware it is not just for students to get their homework done, I truly am trying to learn this language and the assignment was due last week. I know I'm supposed to pass the new string back to main but do not understand why the code I have wasn't working. I'll do better to make sure it doesn't look as if I'm just asking for help in the future though!

Comment: Hopefully this explanation will help, your code does not call the function `str_func()` that you define below your `main()` function. The line `print(str_func)` should have given a `NameError` that the name 'str_func' is not defined.

Comment: @scorreia Not at all, `str_func` is well defined at the time of the calling. The `print(str_func)` line should output something like `<function str_func at 0x0123456789ABCDEF>'

Comment: @MathiasEttinger oh you're right! my mistake...i was running only a small part of the code in IDLE. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
test = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'

def changestring(string):
    for x in 'aeiou':
        string = string.replace(x, '*')
    return string

changestring(test)
'qw*rty***p*sdfghjklzxcvbnm'
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why creating a list for the vowels, strings are iterable too: `for x in 'auieo'`.

Comment: yes I believe so! gonna try and incorporate those steps in and see if I can finally get this program to work, thank you Nils!

Comment: Nils I can't thank you enough for the quick help, I am still getting an error before the Guido word changes to G**d* but other than that the program is a success! Huge creds to everyone out there that helps us new programmers

Comment: @Jfalcone - Are you getting same error? or something else?

Comment: <function str_func at 0x0310F270> is the error i receive before G**d* and after "after chopping then name we get uid"

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
import re
def main():
    #Using "raw_input" instead of "input"
    name = raw_input('Enter your first name: ')

    print(name)

    ### print name with spaces in between characters
    spaces = ''
    for ch in name:
        spaces = spaces + ch + ' '
    print(spaces[:-1]) # to get rid of space after e

    print('name in caps is,',name.upper())  # print name in all caps

    print('After chopping the name we get',name[1:4])

    new_name=str_func(name)
    print(new_name)

def str_func(value):
    #re is regular expression module. It will match string "Guido" and re.IGNORECASE makes it case insensitive.
    #When value will Guido, it will be returned as it is.
    if re.match(r"Guido",value,re.IGNORECASE):
        return value
    else:
        for x in "aeiou":
            value= value.replace(x, '*')
        return value

main()
```

Output

```
C:\Users\Dinesh Pundkar\Desktop>python a.py
Enter your first name: Guido
Guido
G u i d o
('name in caps is,', 'GUIDO')
('After chopping the name we get', 'uid')
Guido

C:\Users\Dinesh Pundkar\Desktop>python a.py
Enter your first name: Jfalcone
Jfalcone
J f a l c o n e
('name in caps is,', 'JFALCONE')
('After chopping the name we get', 'fal')
Jf*lc*n*

C:\Users\Dinesh Pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: the name was just supposed to stay Guido but huge thanks Dinesh for the even better looking program, this will definitely come in handy as I'm still getting the hang of defining functions within functions and returning them! Many many thanks

Comment: @Jfalcone - But in pseudo code you have mentioned that vowels should be replaced by *.

Comment: the vowels should be replaced yes, but the name guido is supposed to say the same for the purpose of this example. (also the call to print function doesn't work in the above program)

Comment: print new_name needs to be print(new_name) and raw input isn't working. took off raw_ and it works 90% but doesn't replace the vowels with asterisks. Loving that you're still trying to get it to work though! always great to see how determined programmers are

Comment: @Jfalcone Changed print new_name to print(new_name). Everything is working in my case. You can check the demo output I have pasted. For which word , vowels are not getting replaced by *? Please paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided a solution to your immediate problem but I’ll try to improve the whole code. I don't know what functions you've been introduced to so I might provide both a naive and a pythonic implementation for each steps.

- To start with, you did not answered question 2: print the length of the input string. You can either count them manually:

  ```
  size = 0
  for letter in name:
      size += 1
  print(size)
  ```

  or use the built-in function `len`:

  ```
  size = len(name)
  print(size) # or print(len(name)) if you don't need the intermediate variable
  ```
- You can improve the spacing of your input using the `join` method of strings:

  ```
  spaced = ' '.join(name)
  print(spaced) # or print(' '.join(name)) if you don't need spaced
  ```

  You can pass any iterable of strings to `join` and a string fits.
- Your slicing take the second, third and fourth letter of your input. No matter what its length is. You need to either make use of the lenght of the string computed earlier:

  ```
  sliced = name[1:size-1]
  print(sliced)
  ```

  or use negative numbers in the slice notation to count from the end of the string:

  ```
  print(name[1:-1])
  ```
- You're required to write a function and call it to mutate the string. You’ll thus have to call it like:

  ```
  mutated = str_func(name)
  print(mutated)
  ```

  The function can either iterate over the original string:

  ```
  def str_func(original):
      copy = ''
      for letter in original:
          if letter in 'auieoy':
              copy += '*'
          else:
              copy += letter
      return copy
  ```

  or use `replace`:

  ```
  def str_func(original):
      copy = original
      for vowel in 'aeuioy':
          copy = copy.replace(vowel, '*')
      return copy
  ```

  You can even use `translate` which can be a better fit in a more general use:

  ```
  def str_func(original):
      from string import maketrans
      vowels = 'auieoy'
      return original.translate(maketrans(vowels, '*' * len(vowels)))
  ```

Assembling all that together:

```
from string import maketrans

def do_stuff():
    name = input('Enter your first name: ')
    print('Your input is', name)
    print('It\'s length is', len(name))
    print('Adding spaces:', ' '.join(name))
    print('Capitalizing it:', name.upper())
    print('Chopping it:', name[1:-1])
    mutated = str_func(name)
    print('Removing vowels:', mutated)

def str_func(original):
    vowels = 'auieoy'
    return original.translate(maketrans(vowels, '*' * len(vowels)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_stuff()
```